# Grouping data of one type in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, group-by

I have to group certain types of data in to one row in the view. I don't know how to approach for this type of result in SQL Server.

Table  data:

```
| Process   | StartDate | EndDate      |
+-----------+-----------+--------------+ 
| A1        | 05-06-2018|     NULL     | 
| A2        |    NULL   | 08-03-2018   | --Here A1 & A2 are same process
| B1        | 03-02-2018|     NULL     |
| C1        | 07-06-2018|     NULL     | 
| C2        |    NULL   | 09-03-2018   | --Here C1 & C2 are same process
```

Desired output:

```
| Process   | StartDate | EndDate      |
+-----------+-----------+--------------+
| A         | 05-06-2018|  08-03-2018  | 
| B         | 03-02-2018|     NULL     | 
| C         | 07-06-2018|   09-03-2018 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have stored the data in badly manner, it should have separate column one for `serial #` & other for `process` but you can do :

```
select left(process, 1), max(startdate) as sartdate, max(enddate) as enddate
from data d
group by left(process, 1);
```

Based on comment you can also do :

```
select dd.Process, max(startdate) as sartdate, max(enddate) as enddate
from data d cross apply
     ( values (case when Process in ('A1','A2') then 'A'
                    when Process = 'B1' then 'B'
                    when Process in ('C1','C2') then 'C' 
               end) 
     ) dd(Process)
group by dd.Process;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
select left(process, 1) as process, max(startdate) as startdate), max(enddate) as enddate
from data
group by left(process, 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

use case when

```
select case when Process  in ('A1','A2') then 'A' 
            when Process  in ('C1','C2') then 'C' 
             else Process  as p,max(StartDate),max(EndDate)
 from t
group by case when Process  in ('A1','A2') then 'A' 
            when Process  in ('C1','C2') then 'C' 
             else Process
```